# jquery: TypeError: $.confirm is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im using jquery.confirm.js

I included the jquery.confirm.js file but it shows the error like below:

```
TypeError: $.confirm is not a function  

$.confirm({
```

Comment: is there any other error in your console

Comment: no it shows the above error only

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: Are you loading whatever plugin adds the `confirm` jQuery function correctly? Because it's not part of the base functionality as far as I know.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnName('someText')">Action</a>

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have both `jQuery` and `jQuery confirm` libraries loaded and that the core `jQuery` library is loaded first.

For example:

```
 <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="js/lib/jquery.confirm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im using jquery.min.js

Comment: It's the same thing, the `jquery.min.js` has to be loaded before `jquery.confirm.js`

Comment: I include many jquery files. I add the jquery.confirm.js atlast. Now it s working.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="js/jAlert-v3.js"></script>
```

useing this library you can do with this way.

```
$.('someButton').click(confirm);

function confirm()
{
  $.jAlert({'type': 'confirm', 'onConfirm': function(){
    console.log('Confirmed');    
  }, 'onDeny': function(){
    console.log('Denied');    
  } });
}
```

Comment: You should have provided the documentation. Also, version 4 is available! http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/

Answer (score 0):

I would check the compatibility of jquery.confirm.js. If you are using jQuery v1.9 and above, some jQuery plugins are not compatible. So check the jquery.confirm.js version and who its compatible with.